# How to upload huge files to Ceph/GlsuterFS through openshift/k8s PVC

Tags: openshift, ceph, glusterfs, kubernetes

Now I wanna run a machine learning pod in openshift,  but I need to upload some data like training set to the pod, and better to the PV when considering persistence. Is there some apis helpful on this?

Comment: Have you tried using ``oc rsync`` to copy it to a volume mounted in the running pod?

Comment: This works when using oc and connecting  to the openshift cluster. But what should we do without oc and want to upload files remotely

Comment: You can run ``oc rsync`` with the ``--loglevel 9`` option and it will show what REST API endpoints it is using underneath. They may help you work out what you need to do if for some reason you don't want to just use ``oc``.

Answer (score 0):

Attach PV to pod. Then you you can use [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp).

For example
`kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/your_pv/bar_dir`

`/your_pv` should be specified in Pods spec.volumeMounts to use your PVC.